# WEB API 2 Authentication and authorization

Tags: cordova, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Phone gap to develop my app, with Asp.net WEB API 2 as my back-end.
I want to use authentication and authorization for the user.

Currently, I am using deviceUUID of the device to log in. I wanted to know the best and secure way in Asp.net WEBAPI 2 for authentication. Can anyone help? Any links to material regarding this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this very good tutorial for setting up authorization and authentication using ASP.Net Identity 2. 
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Also if hosting in Azure there are API Apps that can give you access control without extra code here - I haven't tried this out yet, however.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-authentication